# If we are sure dark matter is not modified space producing gravity can we spot an object deacceleration while moving through a dark matter cloud?

Tags: acceleration, dark-matter

Can a moving object deacceleration caused by interaction with enviroment be measured while the object passes through a region populated by dark matter?

Comment: What is “modified space”?

Comment: @Ghoster Think about this just as we dont know enogh about that phenomena  the only way is to make speculations but not totally without any sense...

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, but this site is not for making speculations. It is for asking questions about mainstream physics. There is no such thing as “modified space” in mainstream physics.

Comment: I assume that you meant "Modified Newtonian Gravity" (MOND). Can we see gravitational effects of a dark matter cloud on object moving through it? Yes, we absolutely could. It would take very precise measurements using a space probe designed specifically for that purpose, but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not exactly sure what your question is asking, but my best guess is that you’re interested in what kind of acceleration an object experiences when it moves through space that has dark matter in it.

One of the first hints at dark matter came from the unexpected rotation curves of the stars orbiting inside galaxies (early work was done by people like Lord Kelvin (1884), Fritz Zwicky (1933), and Vera Rubin (1962)).

Instead of ‘deacceleration’ like you mention, research into rotation curves led to the idea that centripetal accelerations are higher than expected. Dark matter was the term used to explain the ‘missing mass’ holding the stars in and preventing them from flying away while they orbit at high velocities. So in this way, dark matter allows *extra* acceleration on objects moving through a dark matter cloud as opposed to ‘deacceleration’ like you mention in your question.